# Getting Play Framework works with Gradle and IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, playframework

I'm trying to build my web application with **Play Framework** using ***Gradle*** as a build tool. My IDE is ***IntelliJ Idea***.

I use Play with ***Java*** so I don't want to use ***SBT*** in my project. But it seems Play's not supported fully by ***IntelliJ Idea*** because the project structure is quite different. IntelliJ can't recognize it.

After a while googling, I found a solution, adding this script in `build.gradle`:

```
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("app")
        testSourceDirs += file("test")
        scopes.COMPILE = [plus: [configurations.play], minus: []]
        scopes.RUNTIME = [plus: [configurations.playRun], minus:[configurations.play]]
        scopes.TEST = [plus: [configurations.playTest], minus: [configurations.playRun]]
    }
}
```

But there is a problem, each time I open the project, I have to re-run idea task to make IntelliJ recognize the Play's structure.

Is there any way that's better than mine?

Thank you so much!

---

My Github example: https://github.com/TranNgocKhoa/play-gradle-intellij-example.

My `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'play'
    id 'idea'
}

def playVersion = "2.6.7"
def scalaVersion = System.getProperty("scala.binary.version", /* default = */ "2.11")

model {
    components {
        play {
            platform play: playVersion, scala: scalaVersion, java: '1.8'
            injectedRoutesGenerator = true

            sources {
                twirlTemplates {
                    defaultImports = TwirlImports.JAVA
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


def dependencyFor(String lib, String scalaVersion, String version) {
    return lib + "_" + scalaVersion + ":" + version
}

dependencies {
    play dependencyFor("com.typesafe.play:play-guice", scalaVersion, playVersion)
    play dependencyFor("com.typesafe.play:play-logback", scalaVersion, playVersion)
    play dependencyFor("com.typesafe.play:filters-helpers", scalaVersion, playVersion)
    play dependencyFor("com.typesafe.play:play-java-jpa", scalaVersion, playVersion)

    play "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.2.Final"
    play "com.h2database:h2:1.4.197"

}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        name "lightbend-maven-releases"
        url "https://repo.lightbend.com/lightbend/maven-release"
    }
    ivy {
        name "lightbend-ivy-release"
        url "https://repo.lightbend.com/lightbend/ivy-releases"
        layout "ivy"
    }
}

idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("app")
        testSourceDirs += file("test")
        scopes.COMPILE = [plus: [configurations.play], minus: []]
        scopes.RUNTIME = [plus: [configurations.playRun], minus: [configurations.play]]
        scopes.TEST = [plus: [configurations.playTest], minus: [configurations.playRun]]
    }
}
```

I'm using `Java 8`, `Gradle 5.4`, `Play 2.6.7`

Comment: IDE will configure the project structure automatically provided that you have configured it in Gradle itself properly. Can you build and run project by Gradle from command line? Have you configured Gradle play plugin: https://gradle.github.io/playframework ?

Comment: I run the project properly by command line and I added configuration using Gradle Play plugin. You can take a look at my example project.

Answer (score 0):

The below setup works now with some finessing required to get the rest of your dependencies up and running.

```
plugins {
    id 'play'
    id 'idea'
}
# replace with
plugins {
    id 'idea'
    id 'org.gradle.playframework' version '0.9'
}
```

The next step is to execute `gradle idea` and you should be able to just import the folder and intellij. If that is not the case go to Build tools -> Gradle and select use gradle